# UIActivityViewController strange behaviour in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have used UIActivityViewController with share options.

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];


NSMutableArray *ar2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, nil];

NSArray *itemsToShare =  @[textToShare,url];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[activityVC setValue:@"Sample - Share" forKey:@"subject"];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = ar2;
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But it is showing with some white view and AirDrop name as "null'. Can anyone suggest me a solution...[image]

Comment: The iPhone seems to look like a 4 or a 4s; however AirDrop is only supported by iPhone 5 or iPhone 5s.

Comment: @MetinSay this is iPhone 5. i have cropped the image from full size so its looks like small.

Comment: It looks like there's something else strange going on with your `ActivityViewController` - why are there white bands behind each of the 3 main sections? Those should be translucent as well. Are you trying to alter the ViewController in any way?

Comment: @JamesFrost no i didnt alter anything in ViewController.

Comment: I've never set the subject like that before. That's the only line that seems off. This is on an iPhone 5 device running iOS 7 ? 7.1?

Comment: Are you doing this for a jailbroken development? Because subject is private?

Comment: Did you check in "Photos" app while sharing a photo is it coming (null) or not in place of AirDrop.

Answer (score 0):

I have test you code and it is working fine for me. I am using iPod5 touch and iOS 7.1.2
i have a little suggestion. Try to call your code with a delay. like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(shareActivityView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Your method shareActivityView seems:

```
-(void)shareActivityView
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];


    NSMutableArray *ar2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,       UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint,  UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, nil];

    NSArray *itemsToShare =  @[textToShare,url];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [activityVC setValue:@"Sample - Share" forKey:@"subject"];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = ar2;
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This is weird but sometimes it works.